# Sorting the documents by ignoring the case in Mongodb?

Tags: regex, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, case-insensitive

We are using old version of Mongodb so collation does not work and we not using indexes.
Documents are saved in MongoDB collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5223850fa89de4a9f691dacf"), "name" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52238511a89de4a9f691dad0"), "name" : "c" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52238515a89de4a9f691dad1"), "name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52238522a89de4a9f691dad2"), "name" : "z" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5223852ea89de4a9f691dad3"), "name" : "X" }
```

I am querying, sorting by name:

```
db.collection.find().sort({name:1});
```

and the result is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52238515a89de4a9f691dad1"), "name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5223850fa89de4a9f691dacf"), "name" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5223852ea89de4a9f691dad3"), "name" : "X" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52238511a89de4a9f691dad0"), "name" : "c" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52238522a89de4a9f691dad2"), "name" : "z" }
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/OkphOyxTMo2

Use [$toLower](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) to convert name to the lower case in `caseInsensitiveName` and perform `$sort` on it.

> Converts a string to lowercase, returning the result.

you can use [$toUpper](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/) as well.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      caseInsensitiveName: {
        $toLower: "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      caseInsensitiveName: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with [Collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/index.html):

```
db.collection.find({}).collation({strength: 1}).sort({ name: 1 })
```